# NS Binding Aborted call in the Sitecatalyst call during a button click action

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I am getting an NS Binding aborted call while passing data to Sitecatalyst upon a button click.  An scAdd event is getting called but after that the tag is not able to access all the data.  Some data is being sent while some is not.  I tried to add a timeout after firing the event but it did not work. I've seen the s.tl() being suggested  as the cause of this error but what is the change that needs to be made in that function to avoid this error?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's nothing to worry about. Adobe's servers respond with a 1x1 transparent pixel, so the user's browser does not need to wait for that to render.

You can refer to this KB article for more details on NS_BINDING_ABORTED and how it relates to Adobe Analytics:

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/debugger_ns_binding.html

You can also check the [Analytics Community](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/analytics-forum/adobe-analytics.html) for any follow up questions.